# Insert function for Ternary Search Tree - C

Tags: c, data-structures

I am new to C and am trying to code up a data structure, primarily, a ternary search tree. I am working under the assumption (for now) that valid char inputs are being passed in. I am having some issues with my insert function. Note that I am also inserting the original string in the last TSTnode where the last character of str will also be held.

Here is what I have so far

```
struct TSTnode {
    char* word; // NULL if no word ends here
    char self;
    struct TSTnode *left, *sub, *right;
};


int insert_tst(struct TSTnode** tree, const char* str) {
    return _insert(tree, str, 0);
}


int _insert(struct TSTnode** tree, const char* str, int position) {

    if((*tree) == NULL) {
        *tree = new_tst_node(*(str+position));
        position = position + 1;
        if(*(str+position) == '\0') {
            (*tree)->word = strcpy((*tree)->word,str);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    else if ((*tree)->self > *(str+position)) {
        position = position + 1;
        _insert( &((*tree)->left), str, position);
    }

    else if ((*tree)->self < *(str+position)) {
        position = position + 1;
        _insert( &((*tree)->right), str, position);
    }
    else {
        position = position + 1;
        _insert( &((*tree)->sub), str, position);
    } 
    return 0;

}




struct TSTnode* new_tst_node(char self) {
    struct TSTnode* newNode = (struct TSTnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct 
TSTnode));

    if (newNode == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    newNode->word = NULL;
    newNode->self = self;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    newNode->sub = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
```

Here is how I am testing:

```
struct TSTnode* tree = NULL;
char* words[1] = {"hello"};

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (insert_tst(&tree, words[i]) == 0) {
            //print some error
    } 
       else { //success }
```

EDIT - My issue is that none of my conditional branches are being taken and the insert function simply goes straight to return 0.

Comment: Mmm what's your question?

Comment: If you have issues, do explain those issues. It's much harder to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Names starting with underscore at file-scope are reserved for the implementation. You must not use them.

Comment: I see. Will bear that in mind. Surely that doesn't affect the functionality, does it?

Comment: Probably not, but no way to know. That's the whole point of them being reserved: They could do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: You confusingly use `tree` for both `TSTnode*` and `TSTnode**`. I'm going to use `tree_ptr` for the latter, and pretend that you did the same.*

---

Your claim is false. The body of `if((*tree_ptr) == NULL)` is executed. You do have a number of problems, though.

1. You don't handle the case where `*tree_ptr == NULL && *(str+position+1) != '\0'`.
2. You don't correctly handle the case where `*tree_ptr != NULL && *(str+position+1) == '\0'`.
3. You always return `0` when `*tree_ptr != NULL || str[1] != '\0'`.
4. You never allocate `word`, but you deference it. The thing is, you shouldn't be storing the string again anyway!
5. You don't handle the case where `str[0] == '\0'` (empty string).

Fixed:

```
int insert_tst(struct TSTnode** tree_ptr, const char* str) {
    if (!*str)
        return 0;  /* Zero-length strings are not supported. */

    return insert_tst_helper(tree_ptr, str, 0);
}

int insert_tst_helper(struct TSTnode** tree_ptr, const char* str, int position) {
    if (*tree_ptr == NULL) {
        *tree_ptr = new_tst_node(*(str+position));
        if (*tree_ptr == NULL)
            return 0;  /* Memory allocation error. */
    }

    if (*(str+position+1) == '\0') { /* If the next char is a NUL */
        (*tree_ptr)->is_word = 1;
        return 1;
    }

    else if ((*tree_ptr)->self > *(str+position)) {
        position = position + 1;
        return insert_tst_helper( &((*tree_ptr)->left), str, position);
    }

    else if ((*tree_ptr)->self < *(str+position)) {
        position = position + 1;
        return insert_tst_helper( &((*tree_ptr)->right), str, position);
    }
    else {
        position = position + 1;
        return insert_tst_helper( &((*tree_ptr)->sub), str, position);
    } 
}
```

Untested.

---

Let's clean this up, though.

- `*(str+position)`
  simplifies to
  `str[position]`
- `ch == '\0'`
  simplifies to
  `ch == 0`
  then to
  `!ch`
- `position = position + 1; return insert_tst_helper(..., str, position);`
  simplifies to
  `++position; return insert_tst_helper(..., str, position);`
  then to
  `return insert_tst_helper(..., str, position+1);`
  then to
  `return insert_tst_helper(..., str+1, 0);`
  then to
  `return insert_tst(..., str+1);`
- Why is recursion being used at all???

Fixed:

```
int insert_tst(struct TSTnode** tree_ptr, const char* str) {
    if (!*str)
        return 0;  /* Zero-length strings are not supported. */

    while (1) {
        if (*tree_ptr == NULL) {
            *tree_ptr = new_tst_node(*str);
            if (*tree_ptr == NULL)
                return 0;  /* Memory allocation error. */
        }

        if (!*(str+1)) { /* If the next char is a NUL */
            (*tree_ptr)->is_word = 1;
            return 1;
        }

        int cmp = *str - (*tree_ptr)->self;
        if      (cmp < 0) { tree_ptr = &( (*tree_ptr)->left  ); }
        else if (cmp > 0) { tree_ptr = &( (*tree_ptr)->right ); }
        else              { tree_ptr = &( (*tree_ptr)->sub   ); }

        ++str;
    }
}
```

Untested.

Comment: Added to my answer.